# Loops inside inventory files?

Tags: ansible, yaml

Is it possible to use loops in the inventory files? For example in one inv file I got:

```
---
ISPs: 
- name: ISP1
- name: ISP2
networks:
- name: network1
- name: network2
- name: network3
```

and then I want to create something like this in this same inventory:

```
from ISP1 to network1 permit
from ISP1 to network2 permit
from ISP1 to network3 permit
from ISP2 to network1 permit
from ISP2 to network2 permit
from ISP2 to network3 permit
```

but I think that using loops I could do it faster instead of copy-paste and write down all of the possible combinations. Is it even possible?

example:

```
from {{ item[0] }} to {{ item[1] }} permit
with_nested:
- [ 'ISP1', 'ISP2' ]
- [ 'network1', 'network2', 'network3' ]
```

will create something like this:

```
from ISP1 to network1 permit
from ISP1 to network2 permit
from ISP1 to network3 permit
from ISP2 to network1 permit
from ISP2 to network2 permit
from ISP2 to network3 permit
```

Thanks for any answer!

Comment: Please rephrase your question. Add example. It's unclear what you ask.

Answer (score 1):

here is 2 variants, 
see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-nested-with-cartesian

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    ISPs:
      - name: ISP1
      - name: ISP2
    networks:
      - name: network1
      - name: network2
      - name: network3

tasks:

  - name:  Using with_nested
    debug:
      msg: '{{ item.0.name }} - {{item.1.name }} '
    with_nested:
      - '{{ ISPs }}'
      - '{{ networks }}'

  - name: Using loop
    debug:
      msg: '{{ item.0.name }} - {{item.1.name }} '
    loop: "{{ ISPs | product(networks) | list }}"
```

Output:

```
PLAY [localhost] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Using with_nested] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{u'name': u'ISP1'}, {u'name': u'network1'}]) => {
    "msg": "ISP1 - network1 "
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{u'name': u'ISP1'}, {u'name': u'network2'}]) => {
    "msg": "ISP1 - network2 "
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{u'name': u'ISP1'}, {u'name': u'network3'}]) => {
    "msg": "ISP1 - network3 "
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{u'name': u'ISP2'}, {u'name': u'network1'}]) => {
    "msg": "ISP2 - network1 "
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{u'name': u'ISP2'}, {u'name': u'network2'}]) => {
    "msg": "ISP2 - network2 "
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{u'name': u'ISP2'}, {u'name': u'network3'}]) => {
    "msg": "ISP2 - network3 "
}

TASK [Using loop] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{u'name': u'ISP1'}, {u'name': u'network1'}]) => {
    "msg": "ISP1 - network1 "
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{u'name': u'ISP1'}, {u'name': u'network2'}]) => {
    "msg": "ISP1 - network2 "
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{u'name': u'ISP1'}, {u'name': u'network3'}]) => {
    "msg": "ISP1 - network3 "
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{u'name': u'ISP2'}, {u'name': u'network1'}]) => {
    "msg": "ISP2 - network1 "
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{u'name': u'ISP2'}, {u'name': u'network2'}]) => {
    "msg": "ISP2 - network2 "
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{u'name': u'ISP2'}, {u'name': u'network3'}]) => {
    "msg": "ISP2 - network3 "
}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to do, but applying login inside ansible code will be messy, So better idea is to invoke any bash or python script in ansible & pass these two list as an argument to that script & return the expected array from the script at the end & store this value to fact using `set_fact`

Example:

```
tasks:
- set_fact: isp_networks="{{ lookup('pipe','python script.py ' + {{ISPs}}  + ' ' + {{networks}}) }}"
- debug: var={{isp_networks}}
```

Comment: nah, I don't want to use external python script for that. just wanted to know if I can do this in this particular way, useing YAML